# How to use non-thread-safe async/await APIs and patterns with ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

This question has been triggered by [EF Data Context - Async/Await & Multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20946677/1768303). I've answered that one, but haven't provided any ultimate solution.

The original problem is that there are a lot of useful .NET APIs out there (like Microsoft Entity Framework's  [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)), which provide asynchronous methods designed to be used with `await`, yet they are documented as **not thread-safe**. That makes them great for use in desktop UI apps, but not for server-side apps. **[EDITED]** *This might not actually apply to `DbContext`, here is Microsoft's [statement on EF6 thread safety](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Task-based%20Asynchronous%20Pattern%20support%20in%20EF.#ThreadSafety), judge for yourself.* **[/EDITED]**

There are also some established code patterns falling into the same category, like calling a WCF service proxy with [`OperationContextScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18284998/1768303) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20877027/1768303)), e.g.:

```cs
using (var docClient = CreateDocumentServiceClient())
using (new OperationContextScope(docClient.InnerChannel))
{
    return await docClient.GetDocumentAsync(docId);
}
```

This may fail because `OperationContextScope` uses thread local storage in its implementation.

The source of the problem is `AspNetSynchronizationContext` which is used in asynchronous ASP.NET pages to fulfill more HTTP requests with less threads from `ASP.NET` thread pool. With `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, an `await` continuation can be queued on a different thread from the one which initiated the async operation, while the original thread is released to the pool and can be used to serve another HTTP request. **This substantially improves the server-side code scalability.** The mechanism is described in great details in [It's All About the SynchronizationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598924.aspx), a must-read. So, while **there is no concurrent API access** involved, a potential thread switch still prevents us from using the aforementioned APIs.

**I've been thinking about how to solve this without sacrificing the scalability.** Apparently, the only way to have those APIs back is to **maintain thread affinity** for the scope of the async calls potentially affected by a thread switch.

Let's say we have such thread affinity. Most of those calls are IO-bound anyway ([There Is No Thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)). While an async task is pending, the thread it's been originated on can be used to serve a continuation of another similar task, which result is already available. Thus, it shouldn't hurt scalability too much. This approach is nothing new, in fact, **a similar single-threaded model is [successfully used by Node.js](http://nodejs.org/about/)**. IMO, this is one of those things that make Node.js so popular.

I don't see why this approach could not be used in ASP.NET context. A custom task scheduler (let's call it `ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler`) might maintain a separate pool of "affinity apartment" threads, to improve scalability even further. Once the task has been queued to one of those "apartment" threads, all `await` continuations inside the task will be taking place on the very same thread.

Here's how a non-thread-safe API from [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20946677/1768303) might be used with such `ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler`:

```cs
// create a global instance of ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler - per web app
public static class GlobalState 
{
    public static ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler TaScheduler { get; private set; }

    public static GlobalState 
    {
        GlobalState.TaScheduler = new ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler(
            numberOfThreads: 10);
    }
}

// ...

// run a task which uses non-thread-safe APIs
var result = await GlobalState.TaScheduler.Run(() => 
{
    using (var dataContext = new DataContext())
    {
        var something = await dataContext.someEntities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == 1);
        var morething = await dataContext.someEntities.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == 2);
        // ... 
        // transform "something" and "morething" into thread-safe objects and return the result
        return data;
    }
}, CancellationToken.None);
```

I went ahead and **[implemented `ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler`](https://github.com/noserati/tpl/blob/master/ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler.cs) as a proof of concept**, based on the Stephen Toub's excellent [`StaTaskScheduler`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/07/9990421.aspx). The pool threads maintained by `ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler` are not STA thread in the classic COM sense, but they do implement thread affinity for `await` continuations (`SingleThreadSynchronizationContext` is responsible for that).

So far, I've tested this code as console app and it appears to work as designed. I haven't tested it inside an ASP.NET page yet. I don't have a lot of production ASP.NET development experience, so my questions are:

1. Does it make sense to use this approach over simple **synchronous** invocation of non-thread-safe APIs in ASP.NET (the main goal is to avoid sacrificing scalability)?
2. Is there alternative approaches, besides using synchronous API invocations or avoiding those APis at all?
3. Has anyone used something similar in ASP.NET MVC or Web API projects and is ready to share his/her experience?
4. Any advice on how to stress-test and profile this approach with ASP.NET would be
   appreciated.

Comment: From what I understand, the term "not thread-safe" does not mean you cannot access the object from different threads, only that that access from different threads must be synchronized somehow. I see no issue with allow the control of the `DbContext` to move between threads, as long as only a single thread has access to it at anyone time. The type of objects you are refering to are STA objects, which are treated very differently.

Comment: @Aron, like I said, there is no concurrent API access, but the API still may fail, e.g. because it uses Thread Local Storage. I haven't used `DbContext`/`DataContext` in ASP.NET myself, but I trust the OP of the linked [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20946677/1768303).

Comment: In [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx?Redirected=true&PageIndex=2#comments) Stephen Toub specifically mentiones that the async/await facilities are flowing ExecutionContext, thus TLS, no?

Comment: @G.Stoynev, no, the whole TLS state is not automatically flowed by `ExecutionContext` and it should **not** be. I've addressed your comment with more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22973396/1768303).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Entity Framework will (should) handle thread jumps across `await` points just fine; if it doesn't, then that's a bug in EF. OTOH, `OperationContextScope` is based on TLS and is not `await`-safe.

1. Synchronous APIs maintain your ASP.NET context; this includes things such as user identity and culture that are often important during processing. Also, a number of ASP.NET APIs assume they are running on an actual ASP.NET context (I don't mean just using `HttpContext.Current`; I mean actually assuming that `SynchronizationContext.Current` is an instance of `AspNetSynchronizationContext`).

2-3. I have used [my own single-threaded context](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncContext) nested directly within the ASP.NET context, in attempts to get [`async` MVC child actions working](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/601) without having to duplicate code. However, not only do you lose the scalability benefits (for that part of the request, at least), you also run into the ASP.NET APIs assuming that they're running on an ASP.NET context.

So, I have never used this approach in production. I just end up using the synchronous APIs when necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "should handle thread jumps across await points just fine"? From what I understand (I could be wrong), they always use `ConfigureAwait(false)` for XXXAsync if EF6, so the code executed _after_ `await` _may_ not run on the same thread the async call was initially made. So basically the context is disposed on another thread. Is this the expected behavior? The doc doesn't say `DbContext` supports any multi-thread calls on instance members.

Comment: @ken2k If EF6 uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` internally, then anything after `await` inside EF code (usually) won't run in the ASP.NET context. But if you don't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in your code that calls EF, then the code after your `await` will run in the ASP.NET context.

Comment: @StephenCleary, it's a good point about thread's context properties (`Culture`, `CurrentPrincipal`, `ExecutionContext` etc). I guess I can make them flow if needed. Regarding the `SynchronizationContext.Current is AspNetSynchronizationContext` check, the idea is to limit `ThreadAffinityTaskScheduler.Run` calls to only those cases when it really might be needed, which excludes `AspNetSynchronizationContext`-aware APIs, I think.

Comment: @StephenCleary, is the statement about EF thread jumps applicable for EF<6?

Comment: @G.Stoynev: No; I believe EF6 is required.

Answer (score 3):

You should not intertwine multithreading with asynchrony. The problem with an object not being thread-safe is when a single instance (or static) is accessed by multiple threads *at the same time*. With async calls the context is *possibly* accessed from a different thread in the continuation, but never at the same time (when not shared across multiple requests, but that isn't good in the first place).

Comment: See the first comment to the question and my reply there.