# COMException + background thread + WPF

Tags: wpf, exception, com, comexception, background-thread

I am trying to use a COM component & activeX component in a WPF application.
I am using these components via the background thread, so UI remains responsive.
But the problem is I sometimes get a COM Exception while using these components. (not always)

Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?
Should I move the code to UI thread, but it ends up being time consuming.

thanks

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace

Comment: @SimonMourier I can give only the following details System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005) : COM error. additional methods are my class methods

Comment: > System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()  > System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()

Comment: @Sandepku, most ActiveX controls need an STA thread with message pumping loop to function correctly. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211998/stataskscheduler-and-sta-thread-message-pumping

Comment: @Noseratio thanks for the link, I agree with the answer, but, exception does not occur everytime. The chances of it happening are very less may be 1 out of 20 times. So I am wondering!