# Waiting on Semaphore may still be executing code on the same thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, semaphore, synchronizationcontext

Consider the following demo code attached to a button on a Windows Form:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

    Invalidate();  // <-- posts a message that surprisingly will be processed while we're waiting
    Paint += onPaint;
    semaphore.Wait(1000);
    Paint -= onPaint;

    void onPaint(object s, PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();  // we WILL hit this!
    }
}
```

Although we are hanging on a semaphore wait on the UI thread, the paint message posted by `Invalidate()` will still be executed while we're hanging on the `Wait()` - AND (of course) on the UI thread.

This *demonstrates* the root cause for a bug which I'm trying to create a failing Unit Test for - without using any Windows Form. I've been playing with custom `SyncronizationContext`s and `TaskScheduler`s for a few hours now but I have not been able to make this happen *on the same thread*.

What I would like to do, in pseudo code, would be something like:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // something magic - this doesn't help:
    // SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());

    SynchonizationContext.Current.Post(MethodToBeExecutedWhileWeAreWaitingAndOnThisVeryThread);
    var semaphore = new SemaporeSlim(0, 1);
    AssertThatMethodHasNotBeenCalled();
    semaphore.Wait(1000);
    AssertThatMethodGotCalled();
}
```

Comment: This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21211998/stataskscheduler-and-sta-thread-message-pumping) alludes to the fact that the `Wait` for `SemaphoreSlim` does use a primitive that also pumps window messages, so yes, it happens.

Comment: Even without that, though (I take your word for it), couldn't `onPaint` be hit here before `semaphone.Wait()` is?

Comment: Not sure the unit test idea will be practical. You'd at the least need to make sure you're running your test on an STA thread that is actually running a message pump.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError and absolutely NO.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, I was hoping for a way to simulate a simple message pump. Practical or not, I need a test that will break if someone removes my bug-fix.

Comment: Are you sure that `Invalidate` **posts** a message? For me it looks like `Invalidate` is calling [`InvalidateRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-invalidaterect) which **sends** a WM_PAINT message. So I would expect the described behavior.

Comment: @Steeeve I'm sure Invalidate() does not call Paint immediately, yes. Refresh() does - Invalidate() does not. I have edited the question and moved it up one line to remove any confusion.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `semaphore.Wait(1000);` with `Thread.Sleep(1000);`? Does the behavior change?

Comment: @DanByström Invalidate() doesn't call Paint - true. But it sends the WM_PAINT message, which will be processed by the message pump that Damien already mentioned. Shortened stacktrace: SemaphoreSlim.Wait() -> System.Threading.Monitor.Wait() -> WndProc() -> Control.OnPaint(). Just make a breakpoint in your onPaint to see the wohle thing.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias onPaint won't be called. Thread.Sleep doesn't pump messges.

Comment: @Steeeve I'm not sure what you're aiming at. I have fixed a bug deep in a library that uses SemaphoreSlim.Wait and didn't expect any reentrancy, which apparently could happen, as my code demonstrates. Now I need to write a Unit Test that will fail if someone removes my fix. Simple as that.

Comment: @DanByström just to be sure I understood your goal: you would like to reproduce reentrancy caused by windows forms + semaphore.wait without using windows forms? Are native windows apis allowed?

Comment: @Steeeve *smiling big and nodding frantically*. I would like to somehow trick SemaphoreSlim.Wait to make a call to my code so I can make the (once) fatal re-entrant call and verify that it is no longer an issue.

Comment: @Steeeve `InvalidateRect()` doesn't cause WM_PAINT at all. It accumulates in the drawing Region. The Region is painted when **the next** WM_PAINT message is sent. Usually performed when `Control.Update()` is called (which in turn calls `UpdateWindow()`, which sends WM_PAINT). That's what `Control.Refresh()` does (`RedrawWindow()` + `UpdateWindow()`).

Comment: @Jimi *The system sends a WM_PAINT message to a window whenever its update region is not empty and there are no other messages in the application queue for that window.* I tought that this means, the function InvalidateRect self will send this message. But I'm pretty sure, it doesn't make a difference here. The WM_PAINT is in the message queue and gets processed.

Comment: @DanByström I've tried out everything I can, nothing worked... I have no more ideas how to accomplish this without a visible window. But I've learned interesting things and am very curious if somebody get's this working:)

Comment: I don't think that it make sense to write such unit test as you already spend many hours on that and the test you write might not even prove anything useful. Simply write a comment in the code about the fix. If desired, you write add some extra check in the code too.

Comment: @Steeeve  *learned interesting things* sums it up pretty well for me too! Many thanks for your thoughts and effort!

Comment: @Phil1970 yeah, with my current understading that's the best/only thing I can do. i didn't want to drop it without having asked here if there was a known way!

Comment: @Steeeve Yes, the *System*, not the function itself, so a message is posted (not sent, it's not sync) and enqueued - it's obvious *where* - which is the whole point here: to be executed, the message queue must be pumping at that point. The first comment in this long list implies the rest.

Comment: It's umm...'unfortunate' that a synchro object names a 'semaphore' does not actually block when there are no units available.  It's not a semaphore and should not be names as such.  In general, blocking calls should not be made in a GUI event handler, (except for test/debug, as here:).  This 'SemaphoreSlim' object is an example of the messes that occur when language designers try to give  inexperienced developers band-aids to cover up bad designs:(

Comment: Does the same happens if you use a `ManualResetEventSlim` instead of a `SemaphoreSlim`? `var handle = new ManualResetEventSlim(); handle.Wait(1000);` And what about the `Monitor`? Does it behave the same? `object locker = new(); Task.Run(() => Monitor.Enter(locker)).Wait(); Monitor.TryEnter(locker, 1000);`

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Same thing. I just happened to find this "Thankfully, the CLR pumps for you whenever you block in managed code (via a call to a contentious Monitor.Enter, WaitHandle.WaitOne, FileStream.EndRead, Thread.Join, and so forth)". So this apparently is considered a great feature. :-/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2006/april/avoiding-and-detecting-deadlocks-in-net-apps-with-csharp-and-c

Comment: @DanByström good find! You discovered what a "pumping wait" is. You could consider posting a quote from this article as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to this question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well, my question really is: How can I mock this "pumping" in a Unit Test?

Comment: @DanByström yeap, you are right, the question is about mocking this behavior. Seems difficult to do it without showing a `Form`. It might be just impossible.