# Does Task.Delay start a new thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mono, .net-4.5, async-await

The following code should (at least in my opinion) create 100 `Tasks`, which are all waiting in parallel (that's the point about concurrency, right :D ?) and finish almost at the same time. I guess for every `Task.Delay` a `Timer`object is created internally.

```
public static async Task MainAsync() {

    var tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Func<Task> func = async () => {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Instant");
        };
        tasks.Add(func());
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    MainAsync().Wait();
}
```

But! When I run this on Mono I get very strange behavior:

- The `Tasks` do not finish at the same time, there are huge delays (probably about 500-600ms)
- In the console mono shows a lot of created threads:

Loaded assembly: /Users/xxxxx/Programming/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/bin/Release/xxxxx.exe

Thread started:  #2

Thread started:  #3

Thread started:  #4

Thread started:  #5

Thread started:  #6

Thread started:  #7

Thread finished:  #3 <-- Obviously the delay of 1000ms finished ?

Thread finished:  #2 <-- Obviously the delay of 1000ms finished ?

Thread started:  #8

Thread started:  #9

Thread started:  #10

Thread started:  #11

Thread started:  #12

Thread started:  #13

... you get it.

Is this actually a bug ? Or do I use the library wrong ?

[EDIT]
I tested a custom sleep method using Timer:

```
    public static async Task MainAsync() {
        Console.WriteLine("Started");
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            Func<Task> func = async () => {
                await SleepFast(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Instant");
            };
            tasks.Add(func());
        }
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        Console.WriteLine("Ready");
    }

    public static Task SleepFast(int amount) {
        var source = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        new Timer(state => {
            var oldSrc = (TaskCompletionSource<object>)state;
            oldSrc.SetResult(null);
        }, source, amount, 0);
        return source.Task;
    }
```

This time, all tasks completed instantaneously. So, I think it's a really bad implementation or a bug.

[Edit2]
Just FYI: I've tested the original code (using `Task.Delay`) on .NET using Windows 8.1 now and it ran as expected (1000 `Tasks`, waiting for 1 second in parallel and finishing).

So the answer is: Mono's impl. of (some) methods is not perfect. In general `Task.Delay` does not start a thread and even a lot of them should not create multiple threads.

Comment: Task.Delay internally uses a timer, that internally uses the thread-pool. As you're currently creating 100 tasks very quickly, I'm guessing you're running out of threads in the thread-pool so new threads are created automatically.

Comment: So the timers are not implemented using a scalable technique ? I was hoping for something very efficient. For example in node.js they use epoll (for linux), i believe.

Comment: 500-600 ms between each task? Could you post the exact timings?

Comment: I read that the ThreadPool does only start every 500ms a new thread. That would explain the delay. The exact timings are difficult to measure. When running threads finish (like #3 , #2) there might be a couple of tasks completing at the same time. But it is definitely a huge delay. It really looks like a bug or a bad implementation of timers, unfortunately.

Comment: The `Task.Delay` operation itself won't create a new thread, but the callback method to execute your `Console.WriteLine` after the delay is over will certainly need to execute on a thread. If all delays are the same, all of these callbacks will occur roughly at the same time. Try randomizing the delay in your example and see if it uses fewer threads.

Comment: Your `SleepFast` method doesn't hold a reference to the `Timer` you create. If the GC runs before the timer calls back, it will *never* call back and the `Task` returned by `SleepFast` will be in limbo (never finish).

Comment: I don't think so. The timer most definitely will register itself somewhere (in mono source the timer register itself by a scheduler) which hold the reference. The behavior you described would break a lot of code I saw.

Comment: Bug is a big word.  It is not optimal.  You can fix it, the point of Mono.

Comment: I would substitute the Task.Delay with a thread.sleep (which really don't create a thread) to compare the behavior. Task.Delay returns a Task and therefore if may create a thread.

Comment: At first I liked the async/await concept, but now I have to admit that it's just too complicated to be "much" better. Honestly "may create a thread". I mean look at node.js, that's a dead simple and very performant concept. Only a single thread running an event loop, if you need to scale up, just fork the process. In C# everything could start/run in a thread. Even using async/await, while the awaiting itself is done in the current SyncContext, new Tasks started using Task.Run "could" run in a new thread. That's an awful concept when you are doing precise(scalable) I/O.

Comment: Have you reported this as a bug to Mono project? I strongly disagree about bad concept. "May create thread" is a wrong wording, there's always an I/O completion thread, which runs the the code after a hardware interrupt. In case with node.js, it will just marshall the completion callback to the node's main thread, where it will be picked up by the event loop. You can easily implement this model with .NET using a custom task scheduler: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20993007/1768303

Comment: I've just notices that there is already a bug report. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17546

Answer (score 5):

On .NET Framework Desktop.

In short, there this special VM thread which periodically checks queue of timers and runs timers' delegates on thread pool queue. Task.Delay does not create new Thread, but still may be heavy, and no guaranties on order of execution or being precise about deadlines. And as I understand, passing cancellation `Task.Delay` may end up in just removing item from collection, with no thread pool work queued.

[Task.Delay](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,5863) scheduled as [DelayPromise](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,291b6f82d3bd29c1) by creating new [System.Threading.Timer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,07930248be93641d). All timers are stored in AppDomain singleton of [TimerQueue](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,49). [Native VM timer](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,195) used to callback .NET to check if need to fire any timers from queue. Timer delegates scheduled for execution via  [ThreadPool.UnsafeQueueUserWorkItem](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,428).

From performance point of view, it seems better to cancel delay if delay ends earlier:

```
open System.Threading
open System.Threading.Tasks

// takes 0.8% CPU
while true do
  Thread.Sleep(10)
  Task.Delay(50)

// takes 0.4% CPU
let mutable a = new CancellationTokenSource()
while true do
  Thread.Sleep(10)
  a.Cancel()
  a.Dispose()
  a <- new CancellationTokenSource()
  let token = a.Token
  Task.Delay(50,token)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `Task` library is designed more for managing blocking tasks without blocking an entire workflow (task asynchronism, confusingly called "task parallel" by Microsoft), and **not** for doing large blocks of concurrent computation (parallel execution).

The task library uses a scheduler and queues jobs ready for execution. When jobs are run, they will do so on a thread-pool thread, and these are very limited in number. There is logic to expand the thread count, but unless you have hundreds of CPU cores, it's going to stay a low number.

So to answer the question, some of your tasks are queued up waiting for a thread from the pool, while the other delayed tasks have been issued by the scheduler.

The scheduler and thread-pool logic *can* be changed at runtime, but if you are trying to get lots of computation done quickly `Task` isn't right for the job. If you want to deal with lots of slow resources (like disk, database, or internet resources) `Task` may help keep an app responsive.

If you just want to learn about `Task` try these:

- [The Task library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [The Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: So writing a high performance server is not possible using the Task library ? (Because in a server scenario you definitely have lots of small/fast tasks.)

Comment: More like you will can use the task library to ensure your server is not being blocked by IO. Tasks won't solve performance problems, but are a useful tool. They are more like 'green threads' or Erlang threads -- they won't make your hardware go faster, but they can help use the power available better. As always with optimisation, *measure first*