# Why exception before await not throw without await?

Tags: c#

Consider the following code:

```
static async Task ThrowException()
{
    throw new Exception("exception 1");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new Exception("exception 2");
}
static async Task Sleep()
{
    Console.WriteLine("begin sleep");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("end sleep");
    Console.WriteLine("begin delay");
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("end delay");
}
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    {
        Console.WriteLine("begin var task = Sleep();");
        var task = Sleep();
        Console.WriteLine("end var task = Sleep();");
        Console.WriteLine("begin await task;");
        await task;
        Console.WriteLine("end await task;");
    }
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("begin var task = ThrowException();");
            var task = ThrowException();
            Console.WriteLine("end var task = ThrowException();");
            Console.WriteLine("begin await task;");
            await task;
            Console.WriteLine("end await task;");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is following:

```
begin var task = Sleep();
begin sleep
end sleep
begin delay
end var task = Sleep();
begin await task;
end delay
end await task;
begin var task = ThrowException();
end var task = ThrowException();
begin await task;
exception 1
```

My question is that why `exception 1` appears after "begin await task" task  but "end sleep" appears before "begin await task"? I think it does not start a new thread before `await Task.Delay()`, it should happen in the same thread like `Thread.Sleep()`, so I expect the "exception 1" throw immediately before "end var task = ThrowException();"

Comment: I honestly do not know why this confuses you? Why do you think it should be different and how? And why / how do you think both are related?

Comment: @Fildor I think it does not start a new thread before `await Task.Delay`, it should happen in the same thread like `Thread.Sleep`, so I expect the exception 1 throw immediately before "end var task = ThrowException();"

Comment: I think this is a very good question and must admit, I'm also a bit confused.

Comment: _"I think it does not start a new thread before await Task.Delay()"_ - no new Threads are started, here. See [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: @Fildor in this case there will be a new thread. Started by `Task.Delay(1000)`. And everything else continues on this thread afterwards, not on the main thread. But it doesn't make a difference on the outcome.

Comment: @Steeeve Not exactly: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47428221/982149. But as you say: It wouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Fildor That's why a wrote: in this case. I'm debugging right now the console app ;)

Comment: @Snowy: I recommend reading my [async intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

> The await operator suspends evaluation of the enclosing async method
> until the asynchronous operation represented by its operand completes.
> When the asynchronous operation completes, the await operator returns
> the result of the operation,

*I wont dive deep into how multithreading works, I've tried to use an over-simplified model to make it easy to understand what is going on here. Under the hood it's a little bit more complicated.

In both cases `var task = Sleep();` and `var task = ThrowException();`, instructions within those methods are executed when you assign the Task to the `task` variable. The difference is that `Sleep()` method does not have anything to return, so the await here does nothing. On the other hand, `ThrowExeption()` has something to return. Note that throwing an exeption or returning a value from a function are very similar actions. In this case, the exeption is thrown way before you access it with the `await` keyword.

It's like sayin: Hey `Sleep()` and `ThrowExeption()`, do your work, I'll get to you later when I'll need your results.

*Later:

- Hey `Sleep()`, give me your results
- I did what you said, I don't have anything to return to you.
- Hey `TrowExeption()`, give me the results of your work
- Alright! I've been waiting for you, here is the exeption that you might be interested in.

Answer (score 2):

This code is

```cs
static async Task ThrowException()
{
    throw new Exception("exception 1");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    throw new Exception("exception 2");
}
```

similar to

```cs
static Task ThrowException()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception("exception 1");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            throw new Exception("exception 2");
        }
    )
}
```

The trick is the exception is swallowed by the task.
Then the exception is stored in the task and when you ask the task's result, that throw the exception.
And `await` return the task's result.

In your case :

```cs
try
{
    Console.WriteLine("begin var task = ThrowException();");
    // 1) Display : "begin var task = ThrowException();"
    var task = ThrowException();
    // 2) Starts a task that immediately ends with an exception
    Console.WriteLine("end var task = ThrowException();");
    // 3) Display : "end var task = ThrowException();"
    Console.WriteLine("begin await task;");
    // 4) Display : "begin await task;"
    await task;
    // 5) await return the task result,
    // in this case it's throw the exception stored in the task.
    // Go to in catch
    Console.WriteLine("end await task;");
    var task = ThrowException();
    await task;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    //6) Display the exception message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already answers here, but as I was also confused, just a few words (too long for a comment). There is big difference between:

```
static async Task ThrowException()
{
    throw new Exception("exception 1");
}
```

and

```
static Task ThrowException()
{
    throw new Exception("exception 1");
}
```

The first one returns a failed Task, here the exception will be thrown by awaiting the task result.
The second one throws immediately an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing the question.
Because everything in your program is executing in sequencial order.

I think your confusion is that
you think you are executing the task in a asyncronous way so you are expecting
other order maybe.

If you want to execute asyncronously you should do this for example:

```
Task task = Task.StartNew(Sleep());
```

Detail your question better please.

Comment: I expect the exception 1 throw immediately before "end var task = ThrowException();"

Comment: Then you have to await the task right before "end var task = ThrowExeption()" :)

Comment: Then just change the order of the commands because all the code is executing in synchronous way