# Can I initialize ViewModel from a worker thread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, mvvm

I am designing a WPF application following MVVM pattern. But when it comes to multi-threading issue, I find my knowledge quite limited. My question is exactly like the title: can I create the `ViewModel` objects in a worker thread?

Currently we are not using any dependency injection so I just create the ViewModel object in the constructor of the `View` in UI thread (I guess it is not the best practice). But now there is a problem: we have one core class, let's call it `CoreContext`, from our legacy software which is responsible for many core tasks, Data Access Layer between our SW and database is one of them. Many of our `ViewModel` hold one reference to `CoreContext` as data member. Unfortunately this class is not built thread-safe. When I create the `ViewModel` instance(and hence the `CoreContext` instance) in UI thread, it is guaranteed that `CoreContext` is only accessed in the owning thread. However, when it involves with some heavy database query, the UI becomes not responsive.

So now I am wondering, is it possible to instantiate the `ViewModel` (hence the `CoreContext` instance) in a non-UI thread so the UI can be responsive when the VM(ultimately the `CoreContext`) is making heavy query?

Comment: You might be better off looking at await / async. This would allow your db queries to run asynchronously whilst still all on the GUI thread.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, apparently, the OP deals with the legacy Data Access Layer here, which might not be feasibly converted to `async/await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to create and update the ViewModel on a non-UI thread. However, nothing actually prevents you from doing so, if you really have to. You would just need to make the whole `ViewModel` thread-safe, i.e., use proper locks everywhere you access the data fields, including property getter/setters. That should be done for the whole `ViewModel` object hierarchy.

The WPF framework will automatically marshal `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` notifications for the data-bound UI controls (at least, in .NET 4.5, AFAIK). This way, the controls will be updating themselves automatically on the main UI thread, as expected.

What's important: if setting or getting any ViewModel property initiates a background operation involving your legacy Data Access Layer, you'd have to carry on such operation on the same thread your Data Access Layer was originally created on. That is, implement thread affinity for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's also how I feel. And that's what's blocking me: we are trying to access data from our DAL class as much as possible since we implement Cache/WeakReference for loading. But since this DAL is not thread safe, sometimes it is hard to use it ion client side. And as you pointed out, since our ViewModel normally have the DAL as member, they should be initiated in the same/dedicated thread

Comment: @tele, this may help to implement thread affinity for your legacy DAL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20993007/how-to-use-non-thread-safe-async-await-apis-and-patterns-with-asp-net-web-api